# Is there any tensorflow function to return data statistics analogous to scikit-learn .describe() or .info() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

While i was learning deep learning , i loaded the dataset as

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

I want to get the statistics of the data like labels, unique values, mean, variance etc. 
Like that scikit-learn .describe() or .info() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Tensorflow doesn't have data analysis functionalities implemented at the moment. You can in principle set up a data pipeline and some summaries to compute stats as you iterate through the data, but there is no one-liner equivalent to `.describe` or `.info` methods.

Comment: You assume this will be implemented. Most likely, it won't. Ever. The focus of tensorflow is deep learning, not data analysis. There are already excellent tools out there for data analysis and I believe the TF team has no interest in adding this functionality.